# make for reproducible research

Tags: r, makefile, data-analysis, reproducible-research

Make is handy for making research and data analysis with dependencies more reproducible, e.g.:

```
# make file
R = R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore 
datafiles = *.csv
outputfiles = *.{pdf,Rout}

.PHONY: all clean

all: fig_A.pdf fig_B.pdf 

clean: 
    rm -f $(datafiles) $(outputfiles)
    rm -rf output
    mkdir output

# produce outputs
fig_A.pdf fig_B.pdf: interim_data.csv plot_figs.R
    $(R) plot_figs.R
    mv plot_figs.Rout ./output

# derive interim data
interim_data.csv: source_data.csv source_to_interim.R 
    $(R) source_to_interim.R 
    mv source_to_interim.Rout ./output

# download source data
source_data.csv: download_source.R
    $(R) download_source.R 
    mv download_source.Rout ./output
```

Regenerates the figures from source data, saving all outputs to `./output`. But can we make things more compact? e.g., by

1. Avoiding repetitions, as in:

   ```
   $(R) script.R
   mv script.Rout ./output
   ```
2. Reorganizing to more generically relate code (R scripts in this example) data (csv) and outputs (pdf, Rout)?
3. Better handling the export of outputs to the `./output` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1) and 2)

You should probably look at make's [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables):

```
$ cat Makefile
.NOTPARALLEL:

OUTPUT := output
R      = R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore
PDF    := fig_A.pdf fig_B.pdf
CSV    := interim_data.csv source_data.csv

all: $(PDF) $(CSV)

$(PDF): plot_figs.R interim_data.csv
interim_data.csv: source_to_interim.R source_data.csv
source_data.csv: download_source.R

$(CSV) $(PDF):
    $(R) $<
    mv $<out $(OUTPUT)

$ make
R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore download_source.R
mv download_source.Rout output
R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore source_to_interim.R
mv source_to_interim.Rout output
R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore plot_figs.R
mv plot_figs.Rout output
```

The `$<` automatic variable is expanded by make as the first prerequisite of the current target (this is why I reordered the prerequisites of `fig_A.pdf`, `fig_B.pdf` and `interim_data.csv`). Moreover, you can separate the rule with the recipe and the rules with the prerequisites (and no recipe).

Note the `.NOTPARALLEL` that tells make not to run several recipes in parallel. In your case it is needed because you have two targets (`fig_A.pdf` and `fig_B.pdf`) producing the same `plot_figs.Rout` side product that gets moved out by the same recipe. If make was allowed to run in parallel mode there would be a risk of race condition.

#### 3)

This is a bit more difficult because your recipes produce 2 different outputs: `*.csv` (or `*.pdf`) and `*.Rout`. And make has not been designed with this case in mind. It is more oriented towards one recipe = one file product. But we can try to hide these file moves using a macro (`R`):

```
$ cat Makefile
.NOTPARALLEL:

OUTPUT := output
R      = R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore $(1) && mv $(1)out $(OUTPUT)
PDF    := fig_A.pdf fig_B.pdf
CSV    := interim_data.csv source_data.csv

all: $(PDF) $(CSV)

$(PDF): plot_figs.R interim_data.csv
interim_data.csv: source_to_interim.R source_data.csv
source_data.csv: download_source.R

$(CSV) $(PDF):
    $(call R,$<)

$ make
R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore download_source.R && mv download_source.Rout output
R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore source_to_interim.R && mv source_to_interim.Rout output
R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore plot_figs.R && mv plot_figs.Rout output
```

The `$(call...)` make function expands as the value of its first parameter variable (`R`) where `$(1)` has been replaced by the second parameter (`$<`), `$(2)` by  the third parameter (none in our case),...

Note the definition of `R`: it uses the recursive assignment operator (`=`), not the simple assignment operator (`:=`) because we want it to be expanded only when needed, just before make passes the recipe to the shell for execution.